# What's the difference between substitute and quote in R

Tags: r

In the official docs, it says:

> substitute returns the parse tree for the (unevaluated) expression
>   expr, substituting any variables bound in env.
>
> quote simply returns its argument. The argument is not evaluated and
>   can be any R expression.

But when I try:

```
> x <- 1
> substitute(x)
x
> quote(x)
x
```

It looks like both `quote` and `substitute` returns the expression that's passed as argument to them.

So my question is, what's the difference between `substitute` and `quote`, and what does it mean to "substituting any variables bound in env"?

Comment: This is a very good resource, I doubt I can explain it better than Hadley - http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here's an example that may help you to easily see the difference between `quote()` and `substitute()`, in one of the settings (processing function arguments) where `substitute()` is most commonly used:

```r
f <- function(argX) {
   list(quote(argX), 
        substitute(argX), 
        argX)
}
    
suppliedArgX <- 100
f(argX = suppliedArgX)
# [[1]]
# argX
# 
# [[2]]
# suppliedArgX
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 100
```

Comment: `substitute()` substitutes the symbol with the expression that was given as an argument.

Answer (score 27):

R has lazy evaluation, so the identity of a variable name token is a little less clear than in other languages. This is used in libraries like `dplyr` where you can write, for instance:

```
summarise(mtcars, total_cyl = sum(cyl))
```

We can ask what each of these tokens means: `summarise` and `sum` are defined functions, `mtcars` is a defined data frame, `total_cyl` is a keyword argument for the function `summarise`. But what is `cyl`?

```
> cyl
Error: object 'cyl' not found
```

It isn't anything! Well, not yet. R doesn't evaluate it right away, but treats it as an expression to be parsed *later* with some *parse tree* that is different than the global environment your command line is working in, specifically one where the columns of `mtcars` are defined. Somewhere in the guts of dplyr, something like this is happening:

```
> substitute(cyl, mtcars)
[1] 6 6 4 6 8 ...
```

Suddenly `cyl` means something. That's what `substitute` is for.

So what is `quote` for? Well sometimes you want your lazily-evaluated expression to be represented somewhere else *before it's evaluated*, i.e. you want to display the actual code you're writing without any (or only some) values substituted. The docs you quoted explain this is common for "informative labels for data sets and plots".

So, for example, you could create a quoted expression, and then both print the unevaluated expression in your chart to show how you calculated *and actually calculate* with the expression.

```
expr <- quote(x + y)
print(expr) # x + y
eval(expr, list(x = 1, y = 2)) # 3
```

Note that `substitute` can do this expression trick also while giving you the option to parse only part of it. So its features are a superset of `quote`.

```
expr <- substitute(x + y, list(x = 1))
print(expr) # 1 + y
eval(expr, list(y = 2)) # 3
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the only answer I could understand! Was so hard to include an example like yours in the help or online documentation? =(

Comment: @LeopoldoSanczyk R documentation is notorious for being absolute trash

Answer (score 16):

Maybe this section of the documentation will help somewhat:

> Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse tree
>   as follows: If it is not a bound symbol in env, it is unchanged. If it
>   is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to a function or
>   explicitly created using delayedAssign(), the expression slot of the
>   promise replaces the symbol. If it is an ordinary variable, its value
>   is substituted, unless env is .GlobalEnv in which case the symbol is
>   left unchanged.

Note the final bit, and consider this example:

```
e <- new.env()
assign(x = "a",value = 1,envir = e)
> substitute(a,env = e)
[1] 1
```

Compare that with:

```
> quote(a)
a
```

So there are two basic situations when the substitution will occur: when we're using it on an argument of a function, and when `env` is some environment *other* than `.GlobalEnv`. So that's why you particular example was confusing.

For another comparison with `quote`, consider modifying the `myplot` function in the examples section to be:

```
myplot <- function(x, y)
    plot(x, y, xlab = deparse(quote(x)),
             ylab = deparse(quote(y)))
```

and you'll see that `quote` really doesn't do any substitution.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, thank you for the answer. Just out of curiosity, why GlobalEnv is treated as an exception for substitute? Thank!

Comment: @LifuHuang I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding your question why GlobalEnv is treated as an exception for substitute, it is just a heritage of S. From The R language definition (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Substitutions):

> The special exception for substituting at the top level is admittedly peculiar. It has been inherited from S and the rationale is most likely that there is no control over which variables might be bound at that level so that it would be better to just make substitute act as quote.