# Tracing functions in R

Tags: r, debugging

I want to trace a function so that it prints all of its arguments at the call
and it prints the return value together with the arguments when it returns the result.
The function trace allows to define action to be performed on entering and on exiting a function call.
Is there a function returning the list of arguments within the function, and is there a way of getting the result value without doing each one of multiple branches
where each branch exits the function?

in the following example, tracing should print a list of both input parameters
(or the function call as text itself) at the call and the return value when the function exits in any one of the branches.

```
myfun <- function(a,b){
  if (a==1) return(b+1)
  if (a==2) return(b*10)
  return(b)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the functions `match.call()` and `returnValue()`:

```r
myfun <- function(a,b){
    if (a==1) return(b+1)
    if (a==2) return(b*10)
    return(b)
}

trace("myfun", tracer = substitute(print(as.list(match.call()))),
      exit = substitute(print(returnValue())))
#> [1] "myfun"

myfun(1, 2)
#> Tracing myfun(1, 2) on entry 
#> [[1]]
#> myfun
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> Tracing myfun(1, 2) on exit 
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 3
myfun(2, 2)
#> Tracing myfun(2, 2) on entry 
#> [[1]]
#> myfun
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> Tracing myfun(2, 2) on exit 
#> [1] 20
#> [1] 20
myfun(3, 2)
#> Tracing myfun(3, 2) on entry 
#> [[1]]
#> myfun
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> Tracing myfun(3, 2) on exit 
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

As [Moody_Mudskipper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270475/moody-mudskipper) mentions, in the comments, you can also use `quote()` rather than `substitute()`:

```r
myfun <- function(a,b){
    if (a==1) return(b+1)
    if (a==2) return(b*10)
    return(b)
}

trace("myfun", tracer = quote(print(as.list(match.call()))),
      exit = quote(print(returnValue())))
#> [1] "myfun"

myfun(1, 2)
#> Tracing myfun(1, 2) on entry 
#> [[1]]
#> myfun
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> Tracing myfun(1, 2) on exit 
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 3
myfun(2, 2)
#> Tracing myfun(2, 2) on entry 
#> [[1]]
#> myfun
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> Tracing myfun(2, 2) on exit 
#> [1] 20
#> [1] 20
myfun(3, 2)
#> Tracing myfun(3, 2) on entry 
#> [[1]]
#> myfun
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> Tracing myfun(3, 2) on exit 
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

For an illustration of the difference between the two, see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834655/whats-the-difference-between-substitute-and-quote-in-r).

Comment: upvoted, but maybe `quote` makes more sense than `substitute` ? (same output)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Added a note that both give the same output here, as well as a link to an illustration of the difference between the two.

Comment: Why do I get the error `Caused by error in `match.call()`:
! ... used in a situation where it does not exist`. In which sutation will it not exist. What does not exist, is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just overlap it with .trace in name?

```
myfun.trace <- function(a,b){
  if (a==1) return({{"a","b"},{a,b}},{b+1})
  if (a==2) return({{"a","b"},{a,b}},{b*10})
return({{"a","b"},{a,b}},{b})    }
```