# How to pass and use a data frame to a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I want to pass and use a data frame in a function that I defined. But I failed. I would like to know how to pass and use a data frame in R.

The code I used is as below:

```
# create example data

testData <- data.frame(man = c(9, 8, 3, 4, 8),         
                       woman = c(5, 4, 7, 1, 1),
                       love = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))


# define the function

polynomial <- function(iv1, iv2, dv, dataset){
  model <- lm(dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + I(iv1^2) + I(iv1 * iv2) + I(iv2^2), data = dataset)
  return(summary(model))
}

# use the function

polynomial(iv1 = man,
           iv2 = woman, 
           dv = love,
           dataset = testData)
```

But I got this error message - `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'love' not found`. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following :

```
polynomial <- function(iv1, iv2, dv, dataset){
  formula <- substitute(dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + I(iv1^2) + I(iv1 * iv2) + I(iv2^2))
  model <- lm(formula = formula, data = dataset)
  return(summary(model))
}
```

You can then use it as you wished :

```
polynomial(iv1 = man,
           iv2 = woman, 
           dv = love,
           dataset = testData)
```

`substitute` will replace the names `dv`, `iv1`, `iv2` with the names of the arguments that you provide in your function call (in your case `man`, `woman`, `love`). Indeed, if you print the value of the object formula in your function you will get `love ~ man + woman + I(man^2) + I(man * woman) + I(woman^2)`. You can also consult a related [stackoverlock question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834655/whats-the-difference-between-substitute-and-quote-in-r) or the [article of H. Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#substitute) to understand better how it works.

Comment: Great ! if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Comment: I have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802355/how-to-center-a-variable-in-a-function-in-r), could you please help me again?

Answer (score 1):

The function tries to find a literal object named `love` in the R global environment, not search the data frame for a column with name `love`. I recommend you read this answer to do what you want using `deparse(substitute())`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36015931/11316205

Answer (score 1):

You have to substitute the variables inside the lm call (see polynomial function below)

And when you provide the variables, it needs to be a string, other the substitute function will not work..

```
    polynomial <- function(iv1, iv2, dv, dataset){

    SUB=list(dv = as.name(dv),iv1=as.name(iv1),iv2=as.name(iv2))
    FORMULA = as.formula(substitute(dv ~ iv1 + iv2 + I(iv1^2) + I(iv1 * iv2) + I(iv2^2),SUB))
    model = lm(FORMULA,
      data=testData)
      return(summary(model))
    }

# use the function

polynomial(iv1 = "man",
           iv2 = "woman", 
           dv = "love",
           dataset = testData)
```