# How to use `substitute` and `quote` with nested functions in `R`?

Tags: r, eval, lazy-evaluation, substitution, quote

I am aware of the other answers on `substitute`, `quote`, and `eval` (e.g.,
[this
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834655/whats-the-difference-between-substitute-and-quote-in-r)).
However, I am still confused about the following scenario. I will err on the
site of verbosity for the steps below to ensure what I am trying to do is
clear.

Suppose I have four functions (i.e., see below) that all take an `expression`, pass it around, and only the root one evaluates it.

```r
f1 <- function(expr) {
    x <- "Hello!"
    do.call(eval, list(expr = expr))
}

f2 <- function(expr) {
    f1(expr)
}

f3 <- function(expr) {
    f2(expr)
}

f4 <- function(expr) {
    f3(expr)
}
```

Then, I am interested in passing an **unquoted** expression to any of `f2`,
`f3`, or `f4` that should not be evaluated right away. More specifically, I
would like to call:

```r
f4(print(paste0("f4: ", x)))
f3(print(paste0("f3: ", x)))
f2(print(paste0("f2: ", x)))
```

and observe the following output:

```
[1] "f4: Hello!"
[1] "f3: Hello!"
[1] "f2: Hello!"
```

However, calling, e.g., `f4(print(paste0("f4: ", x)))`, right now will result in
an error that `x` is not defined, which is, indeed, not defined until the environment of `f1`:

```
Error in paste0("x: ", x) : object 'x' not found
```

I can use `substitute` in `f4` to get the parse tree of the expression, e.g.:

```r
f4 <- function(expr) {
    f3(substitute(expr))
}
```

then call the function

```r
f4(print(paste0("f4: ", x)))
```

and obtain:

```
[1] "f4: Hello!"
[1] "f4: Hello!"
```

The double output is probably because the argument of `eval`, i.e., `expr`
in `f1`, is unquoted. Quoting it solves this early evaluation:

```r
f1 <- function(expr) {
    x <- "Hello!"
    do.call(eval, list(expr = quote(expr)))
}

f4(print(paste0("f4: ", x)))
# [1] "f4: Hello!"
```

If I apply the same logic to, say, `f3`, e.g.:

```r
f3 <- function(expr) {
    f2(substitute(expr))
}
```

calling `f3` works as expected, i.e.:

```r
f3(print(paste0("f3: ", x)))
# [1] "f3: Hello!"
```

but now calling `f4` fails, with the output being `expr`.

```r
f4(print(paste0("f4: ", x)))
```

At this point, I am not exactly sure how or if this is even possible to achieve.
Of course, the simplest way would be to just pass a quoted expression to any of these functions. However, I am curious how to achieve this without `quote`.

Comment: Why do you use `print()`? Wouldn't the examples be more or less the same without adding this additional layer? Or do you want the functions to specifically handle  `print()` statements correctly?

Comment: @TimTeaFan, `print()` is not necessary per see—I only used it to signal any unintended early evaluations of the expression passed. I suppose it is the same without `print()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is easier if we leave the `print()` statement and focus on passing quoted expressions within nested functions.

We need to do two things. First, capture the expression in each function. In base R we do this with `substitute()`.

Then we need to evaluate the captured expression before passing it to the next function (in which it will be captured again).

In `f1` we do not have this problem, since it is the last function in our chain.

In `f2` things get more tricky. Using `eval()` inside `f1` will capture that as well, so we need to evaluate early. In base R we can do this with `bquote()` to create a call and use `.()` inside `bquote()` to evaluate an expression early. So we wrap `f1()` into `eval(bquote())` and evaluate the captured expression early with `.(cap_expr)`. We need the outer `eval()` because `bquote()` returns an unevaluated call.

```r
f1 <- function(expr) {
  cap_expr <- substitute(expr)
  x <- "Hello!"
  eval(cap_expr)
}

f2 <- function(expr) {
  cap_expr <- substitute(expr)
  eval(bquote(f1(.(cap_expr))))
}

f3 <- function(expr) {
  cap_expr <- substitute(expr)
  eval(bquote(f2(.(cap_expr))))
}

f4 <- function(expr) {
  cap_expr <- substitute(expr)
  eval(bquote(f3(.(cap_expr))))
}

f1(paste("f1:", x))
#> [1] "f1: Hello!"
f2(paste("f2:", x))
#> [1] "f2: Hello!"
f3(paste("f3:", x))
#> [1] "f3: Hello!"
f4(paste("f4:", x))
#> [1] "f4: Hello!"
```

The 'rlang' package offers a different set of tools which makes things a bit easier.

Here we can capture an expression inside a function with `enexpr()`, and evaluate it with `eval_tidy()`. `eval_tidy()` supports argument splicing with the bang bang operator `!!` which allows us to evaluate the captured expression `capt_expr` early.

Note that, normally when programming with 'rlang' we would use `enquo()` to capture an expression and its environment (called a quosure). But `eval_tidy()` evaluates this quosure in the environment in which it was captured, and there `x` doesn't exist. So we would need to change the environment or add the function environment to the caller environment as parent. Either way, in this case just capturing the expression with `enexpr()` is easier than using `enquo()`.

```r
library(rlang)

f1 <- function(expr) {
  cap_expr <- enexpr(expr)
  x <- "Hello!"
  eval_tidy(cap_expr)
}

f2 <- function(expr) {
  cap_expr <- enexpr(expr)
  eval_tidy(f1(!!cap_expr))
}

f3 <- function(expr) {
  cap_expr <- enexpr(expr)
  eval_tidy(f2(!!cap_expr))
}

f4 <- function(expr) {
  cap_expr <- enexpr(expr)
  eval_tidy(f3(!!cap_expr))
}

f1(paste("f1:", x))
#> [1] "f1: Hello!"
f2(paste("f2:", x))
#> [1] "f2: Hello!"
f3(paste("f3:", x))
#> [1] "f3: Hello!"
f4(paste("f4:", x))
#> [1] "f4: Hello!"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This makes a whole lot more sense now. I appreciate the `rlang` addition!

Comment: Yes the rlang syntax is easier to understand. It it also helps to understand what we are doing in base R. It’s basically the same approach, just in base R it’s more complicated.